# Could not start Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I create a dynamic web project to develop a simple project,
the first step I want to do is display the index page
and show the title generate by controller.
but it's always 404 status
and no error or exception in log
is there any problem?

**APIController.java**

```
@Controller
public class APIController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.web", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("title", "AM Core Test");
    return "index";
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-         app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.web</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.web</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01      Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>${ title }</h2>
<form method="POST">
    <p>Request:</p>
    <textarea name="name" id="request" rows="3" cols="50">

        </textarea>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
    </p>
</form>
<p>Response:</p>
<textarea id="response" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: Do you see exceptions in your server logfile?

Comment: No, so I am very confused

Comment: Do you see at startup that your application is deployed?

Comment: What is the war name and how you call it?

Comment: I just deployed and run it in eclipse.

Comment: How are you trying to "display the index page"?

Comment: I set the welcome file "index.web" and I expect that it will run the "welcome" in controller and then open the "index.jsp". is there any problem?

Comment: @Bboy820602 I meant, what exactly are you doing to "display the index page"? Do you oopen a browser typing in a link? If so, which one exactly? Or are you trying something programmatically? If so, waht exactly? The answer "I set the welcome file index.web" is not really an answer to my question "How are you trying to display the index page".

Comment: I just run the project on server in eclipse and it open the browser

Answer (score 0):

You have not implemented the interfaces for your controller as you added `@Controller` annotation, But you have failed to add its suppert in the `Dispatcher-servlet`

try adding ,

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in your dispatcher-servlet. Also it is enough to give the url pattern in the controller without extension as below

```
@Controller
public class APIController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("title", "AM Core Test");
    return "index";
    }
}
```

Now try the URL as , **`http:\\ project_name\index.web`** in your browser